# Segmented picker not letting me pick a different selection

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

I have a segmented picker with three options that defaults to the first option. The problem is that when I select any of the other ones, it will not change for some reason.

[image: Picker]

This is what it looks like.

```
@Binding var transaction: TransactionModel

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        DatePicker(
                "Transaction Date",
                selection: $transaction.date,
                displayedComponents: [.date]
            )
        
        Divider()
        
            Picker("Type", selection: $transaction.type) {
                ForEach(TransactionModel.TransactionType.allCases, id:\.self) { tType in
                    Text(tType.rawValue.capitalized)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        
    }
    .padding()
}
```

This is the code for the view so far, and below is the code for TransactionModel.

```
struct TransactionModel {
    
    var date = Date()
    var type = TransactionType.income
    
    static let `default` = TransactionModel()
    
    enum TransactionType: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
        case income = "Income"
        case expense = "Expense"
        case transfer = "Transfer"
        
        var id: String {self.rawValue}
    }
    
}
```

One thing to note, it will work with the inline picker style. That will let me change between those three options, however, I want to use the segmented one. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on with this?

Edit: I actually found that the inline picker style doesn't seem to be working either. I added some code to display a text view based on what was selected, and it never changed from what it said when Income was selected. But that could be due to my code itself. Below is the code for that.

```
 Picker("Type", selection: $transaction.type) {
                ForEach(TransactionModel.TransactionType.allCases, id:\.self) { tType in
                    Text(tType.rawValue.capitalized)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
        
        Divider()
        
        if(transaction.type == TransactionModel.TransactionType.income) {
            Text("Income Selected")
            Divider()
        }else if(transaction.type == TransactionModel.TransactionType.expense) {
            Text("Expense Selected")
            Divider()
        }
```

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 12.4, iOS 14.4.

Comment: @pawello2222 so it's working for you with that code?

Comment: Yes, I only had to add `@State var transaction = TransactionModel()` in the parent view to make the code compile.

Comment: Yup that worked for me too. I used your code instead. Maybe I just don't understanding how Binding works yet lol. Thanks for the help.